# PhpStorm: any way to change file type dynamically

Tags: phpstorm, file-type, file-type-associations

I failed to find any information on how to change file type dynamically for PhpStorm. For example I need to deal with HTML files, which could have some PHP, Twig markup, embedded JS at the same time.

It is of course possible to choose the type via `Preferences -> File Types`, but the pattern can be registered for one file type only, and this is a problem.

It is not possible to enable multiple types for a single file, and it is not convenient at all to switch types via settings all the time.

Comment: You cannot use "Open as" or change language on the fly -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113835 and related tickets

Comment: Thanks! So, hopefully it will be implemented some day?

Comment: Check comments there. At very least https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103297 got priority boosted to "Major" from "Normal" earlier this month .. so it may be implemented in one of the 2019.x releases. Ask that in that ticket as devs/support team should know more than me (ordinary IDE user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use "Open as" or change language on the fly.

Please follow these and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113835
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103297 (recently got Priority boosted from "Normal" to "Major")